# How to find this equation's solution?

Tags: calculus, matrices, exponential-function, matrix-equations, infinity

How to find the answer below equation?

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty A^n = \ \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\
        1/2 & 0 & 1/2 \\
        1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

At first, I thought it is related to infinite geometric series.
However, I could not find the answer.

Comment: Hint: diagonalize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Adding the identity on both sides you get
$$\exp(A) = \pmatrix{1&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\\frac{1}{2}&1&\frac{1}{2}\\\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&1}\ .$$
Take the logarithm (diagonalizing might help).

Comment: One finds $A = \frac{1}{3}\ln(2)\pmatrix{-1&2&2\\2&-1&2\\2&2&-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Telling my friend Octave about the problem

```
>> B = [1, 1/2, 1/2; 1/2, 1, 1/2; 1/2, 1/2, 1]
B =

   1.00000   0.50000   0.50000
   0.50000   1.00000   0.50000
   0.50000   0.50000   1.00000
```

and asking for the matrix logarithm he told me:

```
>> A = logm(B)
A =

  -0.23105   0.46210   0.46210
   0.46210  -0.23105   0.46210
   0.46210   0.46210  -0.23105
```

Testing:

```
>> expm(A)
ans =

   1.00000   0.50000   0.50000
   0.50000   1.00000   0.50000
   0.50000   0.50000   1.00000
```

The numbers seem to be $(2/3) \ln(2)$ and $-(1/3) \ln(2)$.